# SQLite creating a trigger to limit the maximum entries with a given identifier

Tags: python, sqlite

So the idea is to create a trigger that will raise an exception if there are more than 3 entries with the same identifier. E.g, given a table with Name and Addresses, if the name appears more than 3 addresses, then will raise an exception saying something like "You cannot have more than 3 addresses for a given name"

Below I am doing an intent of what I am aiming for:

```
db.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER no_more_thn3_addss
                 BEFORE INSERT ON Table_eg
                 BEGIN
                     SELECT 
                     CASE 
                      WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM Table_eg WHERE Name=new.Name) > 3 THEN
                         RAISE(ABORT, 'To many addresses')
                      END;
                 END
                 ;
                 ''')
```

Unfortunately, when I try that it does not raise any error when I insert more than 3 rows with the same name

Why is not working? Is any better to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks for the help in advance!! :)

Comment: A BEFORE INSERT trigger is fired before the row is inserted in the table. Change your condition to `>2`. You should also create an UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Why is updated trigger needed?

Comment: If you want to have each name max 3 times you must not allow a name updated to a value that already exists in the table 3 times.